# Given two tables with a common foreign key, how do I get all rows from the two joined tables in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, join

I have two tables whose models look like the following

```
class User(models.Model):
    request      = models.ForeignKey(Request)
    first_name   = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    middle_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 128, null = True, blank = True)
    last_name    = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    email        = models.EmailField(max_length = 256, null = True)
    phone        = models.CharField(max_length = 32, null = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

class Sponsor(models.Model):
        request      = models.ForeignKey(Request)
       sponsor_name   = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
        sponsor_email  = models.CharField(max_length = 128, null = True, blank = True)

       class Meta:
            db_table = "sponsor"
```

How do I accomplish the equivalent of this sql?

```
select users.first_name, users.last_name, sponsor.sponsor_name from users,sponsor where users.request_id = sponsor.request_id;
```

Is it possible to do it in a single django query or would I have to get all the sponsors first and then get the associated users? I realize I could probably accomplish this using select_related on the Request object itself but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Do y ou have a specified Request object to filter by?

Comment: No, I just want all sponsors with associated users.

Comment: I think this won't be possible in a single query, since `User` is not related to `Sponsor`. You could create a [custom Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance)

Comment: User and Sponsor are related through the request foreign key. I can do this through sql, just don't know how to do it with Django.

Comment: I guess you want a group by right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django model foreign key queryset selecting related fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380529/django-model-foreign-key-queryset-selecting-related-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, and please give me a feedback if this work for you:

```
from django.db.models import F

User.objects.annotate(r_id=F('request__id'), s_r_id=F('request__sponsor__request__id'))
            .filter(r_id=F('s_r_id'))
```

If you have already got the result you want with an SQL statement, please match with the result you will get with this query.

Comment: `>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> from quartermaster.models import User, Sponsor
>>> User.objects.annotate(r_id=F('request__id'), s_r_id=F('request__sponsor__request__id')).filter(r_id=F('s_r_id'))`

Comment: Gives the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/nics/d/home/tsamuel/tssandbox/nics_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 169, in annotate
    return self.get_queryset().annotate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/nics/d/home/tsamuel/tssandbox/nics_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 717, in annotate
    is_summary=False)
`

Comment: `File "/nics/d/home/tsamuel/tssandbox/nics_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 967, in add_aggregate
    field_list = aggregate.lookup.split(LOOKUP_SEP)
AttributeError: 'F' object has no attribute 'lookup' `

Comment: @tks Django's version?

Comment: django version: 1.6.5

Answer (score 0):

```
result = Request.objects.filter(user__isnull=False,
                                sponsor__isnull=False) \
                        .values('user__first_name',
                                'user__last_name',
                                'sponsor__sponsor_name')
```