# How to retrive data from related table in djnago

Tags: django, python-3.x

Hey I want retrieve all staff information with there respective Operating Hours
please help me, Here is my models

```
class Staff(models.Model):

    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_TYPE, default=0)



class OperatingHours_staff(models.Model):

    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff,related_name='days',on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    day = models.IntegerField(choices = constants.DAYS)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django model foreign key queryset selecting related fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380529/django-model-foreign-key-queryset-selecting-related-fields)

Comment: queryset = Staff.objects.all().prefetch_related('days_set').values()   i tried this but still getting only staff data

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

Staff.objects.filter(
    days__day="SOME_DAY",
    days__start_time__lte=datetime.now().time(),
    days__end_time__gte=datetime.now().time()
)
```

Basically I am querying using [**`related objects`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/). You have defined `related_name='days'` when defining FK from `OperatingHours_staff` to `Staff`.

---

If you want all the data for staff, then try like this:

```
Staff.objects.values(
    'days__day', 'days__start_time', 'days__end_time'
)
```

Or you can iterate through Staff queryset(using [**`prefetch_related()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to reduce DB hit):

```
for staff in Staff.objects.all().prefetch_related('days'):
    print(staff.days.all())
```

Or if you have a staff then use reverse relation like this:

```
staff = Staff.objects.first()
staff.days.all()
```

Comment: {"name":"aarti","mobile":9227890987,"email":"aartidhav25@gamil.com","last_name":"veer","job_title":"hair ","gender":2,


"days":[

    {"day":"1","start_time":"09:23:30","end_time":"07:23:30"},
 {"day":"2","start_time":"09:23:30","end_time":"07:23:30"},
 {"day":"3","start_time":"09:23:30","end_time":"07:23:30"}
]
}

Comment: i want queryset like this which gives staff as well as days info

Comment: Thanks ruddra for your valuable time